# Python read xml with related child elements

Tags: python, xml, pandas, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a xml file with this structure:

```
<?DOMParser ?> 
<logbook:LogBook xmlns:logbook="http://www/logbook/1.0"  version="1.2">
<product>
    <serialNumber value="764000606"/>
</product>
<visits>
<visit>
    <general>
        <startDateTime>2014-01-10T12:22:39.166Z</startDateTime>
        <endDateTime>2014-03-11T13:51:31.480Z</endDateTime>
    </general>
    <parts>
        <part number="03081" name="WSSA" index="0016"/>
    </parts>
</visit>
<visit>
<general>
    <startDateTime>2013-01-10T12:22:39.166Z</startDateTime>
    <endDateTime>2013-03-11T13:51:31.480Z</endDateTime>
</general>
<parts>
    <part number="02081" name="PSSF" index="0017"/>
</parts>
</visit>
</visits>
</logbook:LogBook>
```

I want to have two outputs from this xml:

1- visit including the serial Number, so I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root=tree.getroot()
visits=pd.DataFrame()
for general in root.iter('general'):
    for child in root.iter('serialNumber'):
        visits=visits.append({'startDateTime':general.find('startDateTime').text ,
                  'endDateTime': general.find('endDateTime').text, 'serialNumber':child.attrib['value'] }, ignore_index=True)
```

The output of this code is following dataframe:

```
serialNumber | startDateTime          | endDateTime            
-------------|------------------------|------------------------|
 764000606   |2014-01-10T12:22:39.166Z|2014-03-11T13:51:31.480Z|
 764000606   |2013-03-11T13:51:31.480Z|2013-01-10T12:22:39.166Z|
```

2- parts

For `parts`, I want to have the following output, in a way that I distinguish visits from each other by `startDateTime` and I want to show the parts related to the each visit :

```
 serialNumber | startDateTime|number|name|index|
 -------------|--------------|------|----|-----|
```

for parts I wrote:

```
parts=pd.DataFrame()
for part in root.iter('part'):
    for child in root.iter('serialNumber'):
            parts=parts.append({'index':part.attrib['index'],
                        'znumber':part.attrib['number'],
                        'name': part.attrib['name'], 'serialNumber':child.attrib['value'], 'startDateTime':general.find('startDateTime').text}, ignore_index=True)
```

This is what I get from this code:

```
 index |name|serialNumber| startDateTime          |znumber|
 ------|----|------------|------------------------|-------|
 0016  |WSSA|  764000606 |2013-01-10T12:22:39.166Z| 03081 |
 0017  |PSSF|  764000606 |2013-01-10T12:22:39.166Z| 02081 |
```

While i want this: look at `startDateTime`:

```
 index |name|serialNumber| startDateTime          |znumber|
 ------|----|------------|------------------------|-------|
 0016  |WSSA|  764000606 |2014-01-10T12:22:39.166Z| 03081 |
 0017  |PSSF|  764000606 |2013-01-10T12:22:39.166Z| 02081 |
```

Any idea?
*I am using XML ElementTree*

Comment: Shouldn't `</product>` termination tag be at the end of the file? Because your _XML_ file should only contain __one__ _root_ node.

Comment: Is `visits` a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @mzjn yes visit=pandas.DataFrame()

Comment: You left that out from the code snippet. Please show us complete code that we can copy and execute, and tag the question "pandas".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example that gets the data from *xml*.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pprint import pprint as pp


file_name = "a.xml"


def get_product_sn(product_node):
    for product_node_child in list(product_node):
        if product_node_child.tag == "serialNumber":
            return product_node_child.attrib.get("value", None)
    return None


def get_parts_data(parts_node):
    ret = list()
    for parts_node_child in list(parts_node):
        attrs = parts_node_child.attrib
        ret.append({"number": attrs.get("number", None), "name": attrs.get("name", None), "index": attrs.get("index", None)})
    return ret


def get_visit_node_data(visit_node):
    ret = dict()
    for visit_node_child in list(visit_node):
        if visit_node_child.tag == "general":
            for general_node_child in list(visit_node_child):
                if general_node_child.tag == "startDateTime":
                    ret["startDateTime"] = general_node_child.text
                elif general_node_child.tag == "endDateTime":
                    ret["endDateTime"] = general_node_child.text
        elif visit_node_child.tag == "parts":
            ret["parts"] = get_parts_data(visit_node_child)
    return ret


def get_node_data(node):
    ret = {"visits": list()}
    for node_child in list(node):
        if node_child.tag == "product":
            ret["serialNumber"] = get_product_sn(node_child)
        elif node_child.tag == "visits":
            for visits_node_child in list(node_child):
                ret["visits"].append(get_visit_node_data(visits_node_child))
    return ret


def main():
    tree = ET.parse(file_name)
    root_node = tree.getroot()
    data = get_node_data(root_node)
    pp(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- It treats the *xml* in a tree-like manner, so it maps (if you will) on the *xml* (if the *xml* structure changes, the code should be adapted as well)
- It's designed to be general: *get_node_data* could be called on a node that has 2 children: *product* and *visits*. In our case it's the root node itself, but in the real world there could be a sequence of such nodes each with the 2 children that I listed above
- It's designed to be error-friendly so if the *xml* is incomplete, it will get as much data as it can; I chose this (greedy) approach over the one that when it encounters an error it simply throws an exception
- As I didn't work with *pandas*, instead of populating the object **I simply return a *Python* dictionary** (*json*); I think converting it to a *DataFrame* shouldn't be hard
- I've run it with *Python 2.7* and *Python 3.5*

The output (a dictionary containing 2 keys) - indented for readability:

- *serialNumber* - the serial number (obviously)
- *visits* (since it's a dictionary, I had to place this data "under" a key) - a list of dictionaries each containing data from a *visit* node

**Output**:

> ```
> (py_064_03.05.04_test0) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045049761>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.05.04_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> {'serialNumber': '764000606',
>  'visits': [{'endDateTime': '2014-03-11T13:51:31.480Z',
>              'parts': [{'index': '0016', 'name': 'WSSA', 'number': '03081'}],
>              'startDateTime': '2014-01-10T12:22:39.166Z'},
>             {'endDateTime': '2013-03-11T13:51:31.480Z',
>              'parts': [{'index': '0017', 'name': 'PSSF', 'number': '02081'}],
>              'startDateTime': '2013-01-10T12:22:39.166Z'}]}
> ```

***@EDIT0***: added multiple *part* node handling as requested in one of the comments. That functionality has been moved to *get_parts_data*. Now, each entry in the *visits* list will have a *parts* key whose value will be a list consisting of dictionaries extracted from each *part* node (not the case for the provided *xml*).

Comment: In this code when there are more than one part for each visit,  only last part is returned. It  does not return all the parts for each visit.

Comment: That's true. I thought that there could only be one _part_ node per _visit_ (as in the example _xml_). Do you want it to handle multiple _part_ nodes ? (changes are trivial)

Comment: yes I want to handle multiple parts,  I am less experienced in handling dictionaries, can you help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

try the following,

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
doc = minidom.parse('filename')
memoryElem = doc.getElementsByTagName('part')[0]

print memoryElem.getAttribute('number')
print memoryElem.getAttribute('name')
print memoryElem.getAttribute('index')
```

Hope it will help u.